# non-standard TypeScript interface/class fields

Tags: json, class, interface, typescript

I'm working on [JSON-Schema-faker project](https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker) where we use following TypeScript interface:

`interface IGeneratorSchema {
  faker?: any;
  chance?: any;
}`

for objects such as:

`{
  "faker": "name.findName"
}`

or:

`{
  "chance": {
     "bool": {
       "likelihood": 100
     }
   }
}`

Now we need to introduce support for `x-faker` and `x-chance` fields that would semantically mean the same as `faker` and `chance`, e.g:

`{
  "x-faker": "name.findName"
}`

or:

`{
  "x-chance": {
     "bool": {
       "likelihood": 100
     }
   }
}`

I know I can create neither `x-faker` nor `x-chance` field in TypeScript interface. **The question is - how can I overcome that?** I want TypeScript to strictly allow only those four fields: `faker`, `chance`, `x-faker`, `x-chance`.

Comment: Supported?? - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want TypeScript to strictly allow only those four fields: faker, chance, x-faker, x-chance

You can declare string properties:

```
interface IGeneratorSchema {
    faker?: any;
    chance?: any;
    "x-faker"?: any;
    "x-chance"?: any;
}

const foo:IGeneratorSchema = { "x-faker": {} } // Okay
const bar:IGeneratorSchema = { bad: {} } // Error: unknown property
```

## Caveat

Extra member are only prevented in fresh object literal scenarios : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html